# Offset Div background on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a div with a background that is offset -500px x -200px, and reacts with mouse movement. The way I have it set up, it only offsets after the mouse is moved. I have tried several times to get .onload to work so it would offset it as soon at the page loaded, but I'm new to javascript and Jquery and I'm stumped.

**Code to move the background of the div:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){  
    $('.landing-content').mousemove(function(e){
       var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 80;
       var x2 = x * -1 - 500;
       var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 80;
       var y2 = y * -1 - 200;
       $(this).css('background-position', x2 + 'px ' + y2 + 'px');
    });    
});
```

**Live example:** http://afrohorse.netau.net/

If you move your mouse around the screen, then press refresh, you'll see what I mean.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: When you move your mouse, that is the intended background position. Take your mouse off the screen and press refresh. It sticks the background to the top left corner. Then if you move your mouse, you will see if jump to where it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your page is loaded, your background position will be what you have set it to in CSS (0, 0 by default, or -500px -200px if you have that set).

Now once a user starts moving his mouse around on your page, you execute the following code:

```
$('.landing-content').mousemove(function(e){
   var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 80;
   var x2 = x * -1 - 500;
   var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 80;
   var y2 = y * -1 - 200;
   $(this).css('background-position', x2 + 'px ' + y2 + 'px');
});
```

Seeing as how you calculate the offset, it seems pretty logical that you can see it jump when it first initialises. For example, if your CSS sets the offset to -500px -200px, on mousemove jQ will suddenly set it at -580px -256px (depending on where your mouse is located).

You'll need to find a way for JQ to set the background position on pageload, so that it perfectly matches whatever outcome your mousemove calculation will give it once a user starts moving his cursor around.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that the image is starting at 0,0 instead of -500,-200. No matter what I change in css it doesn't want to start at the right position. Other than that, everything else works as intended.

Comment: And what does your CSS look like? .landing-content { background-position: -500px -200px; }

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction! Fixed it by removing the "- 500" and the "- 200" from the JQ and then adding

margin-left: -500px;
margin-top: -200px;

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by removing the "- 500" and the "- 200" from the JQ and then adding

```
margin-left: -500px;
margin-top: -200px;
```